# Control the behaviour of @ClientType formula in Lotus

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I ran into an issue with the `@ClientType` formula in Lotus Notes. This formula should show the client type. From the Lotus help:

> Returns "Notes" if the client type is a Lotus Notes client Returns
>   "Web" if the client type is a Web browser
>
> @ClientType is useful within database formulas, form formulas, buttons
>   in forms, and "hide-when" formulas. Do not use @ClientType in column
>   formulas. @ClientType always returns "None" when executed in a server
>   background agent.

However if I run this code in an agent or action hotspot in the client:

```
x = Evaluate("@ClientType")
MsgBox x(0)
```

The result is "Web".

And if I use the notesDocument.RenderToRTItem( notesRichTextItem ) or notesDocument.ConvertToMIME( conversionType, options ) function, the @ClientType formula is also evaluated to "Web"

This is relevant because some fields in the document form in the document library use this formula in the hide when options. When a document is rendered to rich text or to MIME, this field is not included.

Is there any way to control the behavior of this formula? My only other option is to change the hide when formula's, but I would rather leave the design of the database as is.

Comment: I am running 8.5.3 FP1 and when I run your Lotusscript Evaluate code in the client, the result is "None". If I run the formula code directly, I get "Notes". So I am not able to get your results

Comment: I am running 8.5.3 8.5.3 Revision 20110916.0921. Computing the formula in a computed field on a form results in "Notes". I rebooted my PC and now I also get "None" in the evaluate. But I expect "Notes" and the conversions mentioned in the question still fail.

Comment: I ran all the tests again. Evaluate -> "None", ConvertToMIME -> "Web", RenderToRTItem -> "None". The change in behaviour after a restart is scary, but at least it seems predictable now. But everything ran in the client, and I would expect RenderToRTItem to use "Notes" for the conversion.

Comment: What does @UserRoles return in those cases?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's working on a computed field, if your agent gets that document handle then you can get from the computed field. Whereas it will not work in column formula which is already mentioned in help document.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution is to convert the session's convertmime flag to true after your doc.converttomime call

Code below is run from a scheduled agent.
Test 1 returns 'Nothing'
Test 2 returns 'Web'
Test 3 returns 'Nothing'

```
Sub Initialize
Dim s As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim vntClientType As Variant

Set db=s.Currentdatabase

On Error GoTo ErrorHandling

vntClientType = Evaluate("@ClientType") 
MessageBox " Test 1 before converttomime " &  vntClientType(0)

Set doc=New NotesDocument(db)
Call doc.converttomime

vntClientType = Evaluate("@ClientType") 
MessageBox " Test 2  after converttomime" &  vntClientType(0)

s.convertmime=True

vntClientType = Evaluate("@ClientType") 
MessageBox " Test 3  after s.convertmime= true" &  vntClientType(0)

Exit Sub
```

ErrorHandling:

```
Error Err,  Error & " - " &  ", at line "  & Erl & { in "} & GetThreadInfo( 1 ) & {"}
```

End Sub